# How to copy multiple files into a docker data volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container

It may sound trivial but I couldn't find a easy way to copy multiple files into the root folder of a docker volume. I am using Ubuntu **Xenial 16.04** and **Docker 1.12.1**. For example if I have an Ubuntu container with the volume **/my_data**:

```bash
docker run --name my_container -v /my_data -d ubuntu:latest
```

In my host machine I have a folder called **/tmp/my_data/** with multiple files inside, and I would like to copy all those files into the volume **/my_data** in **my_container**. I have tried the following approaches but none of them work:

```bash
docker cp /tmp/my_data my_container:/
```

```bash
docker cp /tmp/my_data/* my_container:/my_data/
```

Does someone know a work around for this issue?

Comment: what version of docker are you running?

Comment: I don't have any problem with the `docker cp` on 1.12.1, in addition to what version of Docker are you running (`docker --version; docker info`), it would help to know if you are running these commands directly on the docker host, or if you are remote, or using Windows/MacOS clients.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually it was easier than I though, just need to add a dot in the host path and it will work as expected, copying all files and folders within **/my_data** folder

```
docker cp /tmp/my_data/. my_container:/my_data
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a loop:

```
for i in /tmp/my_data/*;do docker cp /tmp/my_data/"$i" my_container:/my_data/;done
```

*Note: The specific workaround wont copy hidden files or folders inside the my_data folder.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ballas but my folder also contains other folders.