# How can i use Volume command for display the result to stop the container

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

How can I use Volume command for display the result to stop the container

For example:- 
I am saving the JMeter HTML report in my container but after that container is automatically stopped. 
So someone suggests me to use the docker VOLUME command for RUN the HTML.

How's this possible can anyone help me.

dockerfile last line is 
RUN ./bin/jmeter -n -t ./bin/Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l ./bin/result.jtl -e -o ./bin/Result_Html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950326/how-to-create-docker-volume-with-files-or-cp-files-into-it/49952217#49952217 Look at this create customer dir volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `-v /path/in/the/host/machine:/path/to/html/directory/inside/container` to your `docker run`command. You will end up with a command like:

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/sumit/TEST:/opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/result_html jmeter123:latest
```

Comment: not working
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q1us5t986v9m1l/Screenshot%202018-04-23%2018.20.50.png?dl=0

Comment: you didn't specify the image, see my updated answer.

Comment: have you the shared screenshot link of dorpbox ??.. your shared command is not working, actually the issue is , html report is saved in container and container is stop.

Comment: in the screenshot you shared, you have only built an image, you didn't create a container, So the command `docker run ...` create a container from an image.

Comment: docker run -v /home/ubuntu/sumit/TEST:/opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/result_html jmeter123:latest --- working , but how can i add this in my dockerfile with timestamp folder name