# How to mount dotnet user-secrets in a devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a [devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for building and debugging my .NET Core apps. I'd like to share [user-secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets) between my host machine and the container.

How can I do this if the the location of the usersecrets depends on the host machine?

- Windows: %APPDATA%/Microsoft/UserSecrets
- Mac/Linux: $HOME/.microsoft/usersecrets

I tried mounting both locations, but that throws an error.

- .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

```js
{
  "dockerComposeFile":"docker-compose.yml",
  "service":"devcontainer",
  "runServices":[],
  "workspaceFolder":"/workspace",
  "forwardPorts":[
    5000,
    5001
  ],
  "remoteEnv":{
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS":"https://+:5001;http://+:5000"
  }
}
```

- .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
    devcontainer:
        image: mydevcontainerimage:12345
        volumes:
            - ..:/workspace:cached
            - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
            - ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets

            # Forwards the local Docker socket to the container.
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        command: sleep infinity
```

Docker-compose crashes with an error.

`ERROR: Duplicate mount points: [/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:rw, C:\Users\steven\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:rw]`

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be to use a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) between the host and the container.
Hence, the docker-compose will only reference that named volume.
The named volume creation will be specific to the host though.

For named volume creation based on host path, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49952217/13478534)

But as stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options)

> The built-in local driver on Windows does not support any options.

And for example *device=c:\a\path\to\my\folder* will not work under Windows.

But, given that the windows path *%APPDATA%* expands to something like *c:\a\path\to\my\folder* you can rephrase it as */host_mnt/c/a/path/to/my/folder* and use that for *device*:

```
docker volume create --name my_test_volume --opt type=none --opt device=device=/host_mnt/c/a/path/to/my/folder --opt o=bind
```

For others, this supposes that *c:* is made accessible in docker settings (Resources / File sharing).